# How to separate broadcast of socket.io to a different file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, socket.io

I am using socket.io in my node app, and I created separate file to get io to use it in every layers in project:

```
//socket.js
let io;

module.exports = {
  init: httpServer => {
    io = require('socket.io')(httpServer);
    return io;
  },
  getIO: () => {
    if (!io) {
      throw new Error('Socket.io not initialized!');
    }
    return io;
  }
};
```

Then in app.js:

```
//app.js
const io = require('./socket').init(server);
io.on('connection', socket => {
      console.log('Client connected');
    });
```

and in my controller:

```
const io = require('../socket');
io.getIO().emit('message', "this is a test");
```

Now I need to access broadcast too in my controller to do like this:

```
socket.broadcast.to('game').emit('message', 'nice game');
```

How can I add **getSocket()** or **getBroadcast()** to socket.js file?

Comment: `getSocket()` doesn't really make sense since there's not just a single socket, rather there's a socket for every connection

Comment: Afaict from https://socket.io/docs/v4/broadcasting-events/, you just write `io.getIO().to('game').emit('message', 'nice game');` if you don't have a particular socket handle

Comment: @Bergi I need to access broadcast in another file like routes without init io again.

Comment: Calling `io.getIO()` *doesn't* init the io module again, isn't that the whole point of the method?

Comment: Yes, I want to getSocket() with the same way.

Comment: As I said before, there is no (single) global socket to get. Which socket do you expect that method to return?

Comment: Then I can't call `socket.broadcast` in another file?

Comment: Without a socket, obviously no. But you can still broadcast to all (unspecific) sockets, see the docs I linked above.